# Any BIM (Building Information Manager) in linux?

Tags: design

I'm looking for B(uilding) I(nformation) M(anager) software in linux. Something like Revit, Archicad, Allplan, Tekla, Bentley RAM. All that won't work in wine (under linux). It really doesn't matter if it's free or commercial. Any pretty decent solution would do. Couldn't find any just yet, hence my question.
Already checked CYCAS, but it's very old, very odd (interface) and unmaintained (for a long time).
P.S. Please don't mention CAD software. BIM is not CAD, BIM is much (more) better!! Please don't mention PLM software (like Solidworks, Inventor, PTC Creo, Siemens NX, CATIA, etc). PLM is NOT BIM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bricscad by bricsys. Currently version : Bricscad V16.  You need to get a full (platinum) version of it to get the BIM module. BRICSCAD as such for long time is a viable replacement and clone in Autocad. It saves to DWG that is compatibile with Autocad. Platinum version is circa £800 or £200 per year. You can test it for 30 days free. It is supported on Ubuntu (16.04 and 14.04),  Fedora and perhaps something more. Testing it on Mint I found problems that are absent in ubuntu. 
Please see BricsysTV and search for BricsCAD BIM videos. 
I am confident that that is what you look for.

I found that IFC import and export works, but not great in my view. More of us will get Bricscad with BIM - more viable tool it will become - obviously.

Aha - same license allows you to use the software on Linux, Windows and Mac. (great way for some to deep toes into linux - I think).

Comment: Indeed, that's what i've been looking for a long time ... in linux (especially Xubuntu). This Bricscad BIM module reminds me of older Revit versions. I'm so excited! BIM is finally coming to linux! I gotta say, it's very expensive for the linux world, and yet much cheaper than other Windows BIM software.  No advertise intended!!

Comment: I tried this Bricscad 'BIM' for a bit. It seems that even older versions (as 15) already have this module. The problem is that my expectations were too high. The presentation videos i found to be overemphasized. I really wouldn't pay a dime for it. It looks like a community project, not a proffesional commercial software. It doesn't have the depths of Revit or even Allplan. It's too general, like SketchupUp. I can't imagine any engineer or designer using this any time soon. The CAD part is excellent, but the BIM not.